# Python - Concatenating two images and adding up their color channels

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have two `500x500` images, and need to merge them together and add up their channels.

When I used Numpy's concatenate function for instance, the returned output becomes `500x1000`, and not sure if the color channels are added at all.

The output I'm looking for for merging two colored `500x500` images would be `500x500x6`.

How can I perform that in Python?

Thanks.

Comment: @Dair like having image1 + image2 merged (two 500x500 images). I also want the 3-color channels of both images merged. Does that makes sense?

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out after noticing the dimensions. At first I was thinking about literally adding the RGB values together.

Comment: What does the “adding up their color channels" mean? If the shape of two images is (500, 500, 3), and the shape of  merged image is (500, 500, 6). Then the result is not a normal RGB image.

Comment: It seems to me that you might get on a lot better if you based your question about merging images and resulting geometries on say a 5px wide by 4px high image with 3 channels. This would have the dual benefits that a) you could show examples of 2 such images and b) if you saw an 9 in the output image geometry you would be able to see it came from the 5 and the 4 whereas all that is rather hard with a square 500x500 pixel image.

Answer (score 0):

a couple of options, if you want separate RGB or stuck together:

```
np.stack([np.zeros((2,2,3)), np.ones((2,2,3))], axis=2)
Out[157]: 
array([[[[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
         [ 1.,  1.,  1.]],

        [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
         [ 1.,  1.,  1.]]],


       [[[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
         [ 1.,  1.,  1.]],

        [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
         [ 1.,  1.,  1.]]]])

np.concatenate([np.zeros((2,2,3)), np.ones((2,2,3))], axis=2)
Out[158]: 
array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.]]])
```

to address the above, extract each original img:

```
two_img =np.stack([np.zeros((2,2,3)), np.ones((2,2,3))], axis=2)

two_img[...,0,:]
Out[160]: 
array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]])

two_img[...,1,:]
Out[161]: 
array([[[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.]],

       [[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.]]])

too_img = np.concatenate([np.zeros((2,2,3)), np.ones((2,2,3))], axis=2)

too_img[...,0:3]
Out[163]: 
array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]])

too_img[...,3:]
Out[164]: 
array([[[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.]],

       [[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.]]])
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. When I do np.shape for the first solution (stack), I get (2, 2, 2, 3). For the second solution (concatenate), I get (2, 2, 6). Which would be the one where I would have "two" 2x2 images with the channels added together? I see the second solution shows "6", but I now have "one" 2x2 image, and "not" two 2x2 images. Please let me know what you think.